# Flexbox problems in Safari

Tags: css, safari, flexbox

I am testing some things with flexbox, but I have run into some problems.
I searched the forums already, but didn't find the answer I was looking for, so I signed up here in the hope of finding an answer.

Now I know I should provide some fallback, and I will in the future, but for the moment I can't get flexbox to work in Safari (desktop neither mobile). I tried the -webkit-prefix, wich is suggested by http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox , but it just isn't working.

I'm probably just missing something, but I can't seem to work it out.

I made a pen, which works in Chrome, but doesn't in Safari...

HTML

```
<div class="aligner">
  <h1>Flexbox Testing</h1>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.aligner {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

This is the link for Codepen http://codepen.io/linkerd/pen/vHibq

I would really appreciate the help!

Thanks in advance.

Stef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safari still needs vendor prefixes for flexbox.

Add:

```
.aligner {

  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
}
```

Pen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbamKx

A really helpful tool for avoiding this headache is [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer). It works with grunt, gulp, command-line, etc.

Comment: Oh, so I was just using some wrong prefixes, or not enough. Thanks!
I recently started using autoprefixer myself, indeed quite handy! Thanks for the tip.